# jquery/ajax form another div refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I would start with my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cForm").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            comment: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Empty.",
            email: "Invalid email.",
            comment: "Empty.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#cForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The above code is working fine with the form below, and giving success message out of my process.php fine into div with id results but i have another div before that with id comments which selects and displays the data from the same table where this ajax/jquery form stores the data...I want to refresh that with the latest changes when the form is submitted..have a look at my code first.

```
<div id="comments">
<h2>Comments</h2>
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT name, c_c, c_date FROM blog_comments WHERE art_id='$id'";
$result3 = @mysql_query($query3);
while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{
    echo '<div class="comen">';
    echo "<h3>";
    echo $rr['name'];
    echo "</h3>";
    echo "<h4>";
    echo $rr['c_date'];
    echo "</h4>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo $rr['c_c'];
    echo "</p>";
    echo '</div>';
}
mysql_close();
?>
</div>
<p>Post your comments. All fields are obligatory.</p>
<div id="results"></div>
<form action="" id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post" class="cform">
 <table>
<tr><td><label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label></td><td><input type="text"     name="name" id="name" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label></td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="comment" id="comment_label">Comment</label></td><td><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="idi" value="<?php echo $id ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and my process php looks like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include ('databas/conektion.php');
function escape_data ($data)
        {
            global $con;
            if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
            {
                $data = stripslashes($data);
            }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($data,$con);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            $n = FALSE;
            echo '<p>Invalid name</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            $n = escape_data($_POST['name']);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $e = FALSE;
            echo '<p>Invalid Email</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            $e = escape_data($_POST['email']);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['comment']))
        {
            $c = FALSE;
            echo '<p>Invalid Comments</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            $c = escape_data($_POST['comment']);
        }
        $id = $_POST['idi'];
        if($n && $e && $c)
        {
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO blog_comments (name, c_email, c_c, art_id, c_date) VALUES ('$n', '$e', '$c', '$id', NOW())";
            $result2 = @mysql_query($query2);
            if($result2)
            {
                echo '<p>Your comments have been posted successfully.</p>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<p>System Error</p><p>' . mysql_error() . '</p>';
            }
        mysql_close();
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p style="color:red">Please try again.</p>';
        }
 }
?>
```

what i want to do is refresh div with id comments, once form is submitted.what changes should i make in my code...thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new file called comments.php (with source code of your comments block)
- Initially load comments
  `$(document).ready(function() { $("#comments_div").load("comments.php"); });`
- Then when you want to refresh, just call `$("#comments_div").load("comments.php");`
  ie. from your first given code

  ```
  submitHandler: function(form) {
      // do other stuff for a valid form
      $.post('process.php', $("#cForm").serialize(), function(data) {
          $('#results').html(data);
          $("#comments_div").load("comments.php");
      });
  }
  ```

EDIT:

If you have an ID in your url, then replace

```
            $("#comments_div").load("comments.php");
```

with

```
            $.get("comments.php", {"id": "<?=(0+$_GET['id'])?>"}, 
              function(response) {
                 $("#comments_div").html(response);
              }
           );
```

Where your_id is the name of GET parameter.

EDIT2:

So how about if you try something like:

```
            $.get("comments.php", {id: <?php echo (0+$_GET['id']); ?>}, 
              function(response) {
                 $("#comments_div").html(response);
              }
            );
```

Comment: perfect bro thanks for your help...But there is one more problem now..In my code there is a variable called $id which I grabbed from URL using get method, how do i pass it on to my comment.php which you just advised me to create?????

Comment: user1545078, I added solution for that. Check if that's alright.

Comment: Youre awsome bro but i am really dumb :( i dont seem to understand you here..in my url it looks like this http://127.0.0.1/meerab/view.php?id=16 so your_id should be replaced with id. which i did but its not working...i thought i need to grab id with get method in my comment.php page i tried it with and without grabbing it but not working......I might have been doing something which is awfully stupid

Comment: yes, you are thinking in the right direction. make sure you change ALL your_id to id. e.g. {"id": "<?=(0+$_GET['id'])?>"} And make sure that you replace that previous load in both places (document.ready and in the submit handler). If it's still not working, I would suggest you to see what you code is executing. You can use Google Chrome and with Right Click Mouse use Inspect Element, move to Newtork ,click on XHR, refresh the page,  and click on the comments.php. In the tab headers you should see your id in 'query string parameters'

Comment: Ok I did what you said....n in query string parameters is says this id:<?=(0+$_GET['id'])?>

Comment: Ok. That's weird. The file where the script lies should be in PHP. Is it? It seems that it does not recognize the PHP command and sees it as a string. So basically yeah, ensure that you can write in PHP where your script lies. You can try removing quotes from <?=(0+$_GET['id'])?>, although that shouldnt be the case.

Comment: <?php
 echo "<h2>Comments</h2>";
 include ('databas/conektion.php');
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $query3 = "SELECT name, c_c, c_date FROM blog_comments WHERE art_id='$id'";
 $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
 while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($result3))
 {
  echo '<div class="comen">';
  echo "<h3>";
  echo $rr['name'];
  echo "</h3>";
  echo "<h4>";
  echo $rr['c_date'];
  echo "</h4>";
  echo "<p>";
  echo $rr['c_c'];
  echo "</p>";
  echo '</div>';
 }
 mysql_close();
 ?>  by the way this is how my comment.php looks...is anything wrong in it?

Comment: if i put $id value in my comment.php manually it works fine, like $id=7 (just for testing)...I dont seem to pass and fetch $id the way we want it..and yes bro all pages are .php

Comment: Okay. Let's make it clear. Where is located your script?  The one which starts with <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cForm").validate({

Comment: Hi. Sorry I forgot about you. To be honest I have no idea why is the code not working for you. Maybe you have some specific configuration or I am just being stupid and don't see an obvious mistake. I will edit my answer in a sec and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bro for your help,,and giving me so much time...my head tags look like this altogether now...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cForm").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            comment: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Empty.",
            email: "Invalid email.",
            comment: "Empty.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#cForm").serialize(),  function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
                 $.get("comment.php", {"id": "<?=(0+$_GET['id'])?>"}, 
          function(response) {
             $("#comment").html(response);
          }
       );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  $.get("comment.php", {"id": "<?=(0+$_GET['id'])?>"}, 
          function(response) {
             $("#comment").html(response);
          }
       ); });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, I used your first code with the load method and I set a cookie to pass the variable to work my around...Thanks....